# Proving a perpendicular bisector in a circle

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles

> [image]
> The quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle, $\overline{AC}$ bisects $\angle BAD$, $\overline{AD}$ is extended to $E$ such that $DE = AB$. Prove that $C$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AE}$.

This relates to circles and angles of inscribed quadrilaterals. Any help or advice is appreciated.
The perpendicular bisector is drawn, though gray.

Comment: Hint: triangles $BAC$ and $DEC$ have $AB=DE$ by construction, but that's not the only thing in common.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, angle CDE and ABC are congruent, but what does that lead to?

Comment: You haven't used "*AC bisects the angle BAD*" yet. That tells you something about point $C$.

Comment: @dxiv I see the obvious angles BAC and DAC are congruent. But what does C have to do with it?

Comment: Equal inscribed angles means equal subtended arcs, so $C$ is the midpoint of arc $BD$.

Comment: Also use that $CD=BC$ which leads to $AC=CE$

Answer (score 3):

[image]

- It is given that the two red line segments are congruent.
- $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ADC$ are supplementary, since they are opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral, so the two marked angles are congruent.
- It is given that $\angle BAC\cong\angle CAD$, so arcs $BC$ and $CD$ are congruent.  Therefore, the two green line segments, which cap those congruent arcs must also be congruent.
- Therefore, by SAS, the two triangles are congruent.  Thus, by CPCTC, we can conclude that $\overline{AC}\cong\overline{EC}$.  Since the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AE}$ is the locus of points equidistant from $A$ and $E$, we have shown that $C$ must lie on that line.